# TestNG.xml - New browser session does not open after first one is closed

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

How my framework works:

- methods depend on the previous methods, e.g. step 2 depends on step 1, step 3 on step 2 and so on - what this does is, if one method fails, all others are skipped.
- I added a teardown method with the annotation @AfterMethod hoping that after the test fails, the driver will close and another driver will open for testcase2 (bad way I know)
- running this from testng.xml gives me the following flow: first test case is executed (let's say it fails somewhere in the middle). driver will quit but the driver won't start for the second test case.

The problem with teardown and @AfterMethod is that the program tries to call driver.quit on each method even though the driver is already closed.

```
Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
```

Is there a way to do the following?
**- if test step fails, skip all others in test case (java class) then quit browser and open browser again for the second test case.**
I know @AfterMethod is a bad way to approach this. I've read somewhere that using static attributes for WebDriver is a bad approach in this case. If so, how should I refactor my code to be able to have the above flow? (bold).

Could it be because of the listener? At home I cannot access the tool where I send the results so this works perfectly. At work where the tool can be accessed locally, the listener works, and this fails.

My guess is the issue happens because of the listener.

Thanks!

**testng.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="AutomationFramework">
    <test name="RegistrationPart1">             
        <classes>
            <class name="registration.testcase1" />                         
        </classes>      
    </test> 
    <test name="RegistrationPart2">             
        <classes>
            <class name="registration.testcase2" />                         
        </classes>      
    </test> 
</suite>
```

**Testcase1**

```
public class testcase1 {

    TNGDriver tngDriver = new TNGDriver();

    @BeforeClass
    public void initBrowser() {
        tngDriver.initBrowser("chrome");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1) 
    public void step1() throws InterruptedException {       
        //do something      
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethods = {"step1"})
    public void step2() {
       //do something
    }
```

**Testcase2**

```
public class testcase2 {

    TNGDriver tngDriver = new TNGDriver();

    @BeforeClass
    public void initBrowser() {
        tngDriver.initBrowser("chrome");
    }

    @Test(priority = 1) 
    public void step1() throws InterruptedException {       
        //do something      
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, dependsOnMethods = {"step1"})
    public void step2() {
       //do something
    }
```

**tearDown method**

```
   @AfterMethod
   public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
            takeScreenshot(result);
            quitAndKillTask();
        }
    }
```

Comment: quitAndKillTask(); in this method are you terminating the driver ? and " if test step fails, skip all others in test case (java class) then quit browser and open browser again for the second test case" by opening ythe browser for second test case do you mean for test2 class ?

Comment: quitAndKillTask() - yes, I have driver.quit(); and a line of code to kill the process of the chromedriver.

opening the browser for second test case - yes, I mean test2 class

Comment: which listener you are using ?

Comment: TestNG SpiraTestListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. By mistake I was declaring the driver as null in the initBrowser function.

Answer (score 1):

if you are calling driver.close(), this will close the current window. If there is no open window, the driver quits. So, when call your tearDown, driver.quit() the session has already ended and you get an error.

in teardown, just check for a valid session and then call driver.quit() if any one  exists

Comment: But in the second test class the driver is initialized again.
tngDriver.initBrowser("chrome");

How exactly should I go around this? Cannot find a way.

Comment: are you checking for a valid session before quitting in tear down , if yes then it should create a session perfectly, just put some sleep after quitting the driver , it can happen once you quit the driver , you are initiating another driver immediately even the previous driver is not destroyed completely yet , so i suggest just give some delay after quitting the  driver  in teardown method

Comment: It doesn't work :(

At home it works perfectly (I cannot access the listener and such) so it works perfectly.
At work it doesn't, so most likely because of the listener - it's the same code, cannot be anything else I guess.
I'm trying to solve this problem in the listener, but cannot find a way.